# Flexbox items don't re-order on browser's window resize, but does on Responsive mode

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

When resizing browser window the elements won't transform from horizontal to vertical, instead would just squeeze up horizontally (tested Chrome, Edge, Firefox). But if you switched to responsive mode view (e.g. Firefox CTRL+Shift+M) then they re-arrange all nicely as they supposed to.

Here it is in action https://i.imgur.com/RAPiG1W.mp4

I also have this problem while browsing on iPhone with Safari, but both Chrome and Firefox responsive design modes show they work.

I'm not following what's causing this.

https://jsfiddle.net/pdsh91fL/

```
.main-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}
.main-container .flex-item {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    flex: 1;
    margin: 0 15px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 568px) {
  .main-container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
   }
}
```

Comment: You should post the code you've tried. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: We can't fix a code problem without any code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pdsh91fL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your media query:

```
@media screen (max-device-width: 568px) {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

First of all, you have 2 conditions: `screen` and `(max-device-width: 568px)`, but you are missing the `and` operator:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 568px) {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Second thing: you are using `max-device-width` instead of `max-width`, so it will do nothing on a computer browser window, because is not a device. For this reason the query works only on responsive mode.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 568px) {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

One last disturbing thing: where are you applying the `flex-wrap` rule? You should define it.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 568px) {
    .main-container {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
}
```

Also you probably want to change the *direction* instead of the *wrap*. In the example below I changed the width value for a previsualization of the query in this post.

```css
.main-container {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}
.main-container .flex-item {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column;
 align-items: center;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
 padding: 0 0 10px 0;
 flex: 1;
 margin: 0 15px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .main-container {
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="flex-item flex-item-1">Box 1</div>
  <div class="flex-item flex-item-2">Box 2</div>
  <div class="flex-item flex-item-2">Box 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @user3108268 That's because you are probably misunderstanding the use of flexbox for your purpose. You want to change the direction, but you are only changing the wrap option. Use `flex-flow: column nowrap` instead of `flex-wrap: wrap`.

Comment: the solution was flex-basis: 100%;

Comment: @user3108268 Only if you want the items to be more 50% or more width, otherwise they will continue ordering as rows, because is the `flex-direction` you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the following in the `<head>` tag of the HTML page?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer by FunkyBob on #css freenode

```
<FunkyBob> you need to set the flex on the items so they won't shrink,
and have a basis size they won't shrink below
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u6gLcw2j/

https://jsfiddle.net/u6gLcw2j/1/

```
  .main-container .flex-item {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
```